# Masked input gets data incorrectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

Using VueJS with Quasar framework.

Whenever I use a masked `q-input`,  value becomes incorrect after a toggle.

For example, if I have a default value of:

```
officeNum: 654321,
mobileNum: 12345678,
```

Then I have this code:

```
<div v-if="showOfficeNum">
  <q-input id="officeNum" outlined clearable clear-icon="close" v-model="officeNum" label="Office Number" mask="###-###"/>
</div>
<div v-if="showMobileNum">
  <q-input id="mobileNum" outlined clearable clear-icon="close" v-model="mobileNum" label="Mobile Number" mask="##-###-###"/>
</div>

<q-btn label="Change Displayed Info" color="primary" @click="updateBoolean"></q-btn>
```

It will display:

Mobile Number as `12-345-678`

Then after clicking button "Change Displayed Info", it will display:

Office Number as `654-321`

But when "Change Displayed Info" is clicked again, this is where behavior becomes incorrect:
Mobile Number is now displayed as `12-345-6` instead of `12-345-678` as it originally was.

JSFiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qkxawe81/

Help anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```html
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      version: Quasar.version,
      officeNum: '',
      mobileNum: '',
      showMobileNum: true,
      showOfficeNum: false
    }
  },
  beforeMount: function() {
      this.officeNum = '654321',
      this.mobileNum =  '12345678'
  },
  methods: {
    updateBoolean() {
     this.showOfficeNum = !this.showOfficeNum
      this.showMobileNum = !this.showMobileNum
    }
 }
})
```

You can check the working code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/f5wja3xs/2/

Comment: Hmm.. I tried to run the JSFIddle code and it still truncates after toggling..
Mobile num becomes ```12-345-67```.. Did I miss anything?